# Why is it "marciano" instead of "martiano" in Spanish?

Tags: etimología, historia, pronunciación

In English, the adjective for things (or people!) from Mars is "mar**t**ian", with a T.
This is because Mars comes [from Latin *Mars, Martis*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mars#Latin) where every single case and derived word started with *Mar**t**-* (save for singular nominative / vocative *Mars* itself).

In Spanish, Mars is said *Mar**t**e*, also with a T, because it also comes from Latin.
However, the adjective for something that comes from *Mar**t**e* is **not** *"mar**t**iano"* but *mar**c**iano* with a C.

Why is that? **Why "marciano" with a C but "Marte" with a T?**

Comment: ¿Puede que sea un anglicismo?

Comment: Es una deformación común, tal como, pues, la *c* en deformación (que en latín era *-tio*.  La combinación *ti* frecuentemente sufrió este cambio pero los rasgos se ven en casos cuando quedan palabras relacionadas con otras vocales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In English:**

Latin /t/ turned into /ts/ in Romance when before a *yod* (the sound of non-syllabic [i]). This wasn't an isolated occurrence; many consonants underwent similar changes ([palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(sound_change))). In Spanish this /ts/ went then from palatal/alveolar to dental position /θ/. This sound remained [θ] in most of Spain but turned again into alveolar [s] in America.

From the same root of *marciano* we have *marcial*, with the same phonetic change. This is also how all Spanish words ending in *-ción* evolved from Latin words ending in *-tiōnis*.

English transcription of Latin words does not, of course, follow Romance rules or Romance sound changes, so English doesn't change the original spelling with a *t*, though as you can see, palatalization also takes place here.

**En español:**

La /t/ del latín pasó a ser /ts/ en romance cuando se encontraba frente a una *yod* (un sonido [i] no silábico). No fue un caso aislado; muchas consonantes cambiaron de manera similar por [palatalización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalizaci%C3%B3n). En castellano esta /ts/ pasó de ser palatal/alveolar a la posición dental, /θ/. Este sonido continuó siendo [θ] en gran parte de España pero se transformó de vuelta en [s] en América.

De la misma raíz que *marciano* tenemos *marcial*, con la misma transformación fonética. De igual manera evolucionaron todas las palabras castellanas terminadas en *-ción*, que provienen de palabras latinas en *-tiōnis*.

La transcripción inglesa de palabras latinas no sigue, por supuesto, las reglas del romance, ni refleja sus cambios fonéticos, de manera que en inglés no se cambia la *t* original, aunque también aquí hay palatalización.

Answer (score 4):

Martiano de hecho ha sido un nombre propio desde tiempos antiguos, en el CORDE aparecen libros que hablan de San Martiano, el emperador Martiano Augusto y un tal Acrino Martiano. Aunque no sé si todos estos casos se corresponden con el nombre que hoy conocemos como "Mariano" o como corrupción de "Marciano", que también existía (ejemplo: Flavius Marcianus Augustus).

En todo caso, resulta curioso que la palabra *martiano* sí viene recogida en el DLE:

> **[martiano, na](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OV3ydTJ)**
>
> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a José Martí, escritor y político cubano, o a su obra. *La doctrina martiana.*
> 2. adj. Que tiene rasgos característicos de la obra de Martí. *Un ideario muy martiano.*

Pero nos estamos desviando. La palabra *marciano* se recoge en el DLE desde 1925, y aparece en el CORDE desde 1919:

> *Este fenómeno influye tanto en las condiciones climatéricas del mundo marciano como la propia inclinación del eje y la sucesión de las estaciones.*
>
> José Comas Solá, "Astronomía I y II", 1919 (España).

¿Por qué se usó "marciano"? No parece que fuera una colisión con "martiano", que se acuñó más tarde. Por lo que es posible que se dijera así por asimilación con el nombre de "Marciano", ya conocido y de más fácil pronunciación que "martiano". También hay que tener en cuenta que el nombre en latín es *Mars*, del cual puede derivar "marsiano" o "marciano". Me inclino más por lo primero: si buscas "marciano" en la hemeroteca de la BNE aparecen cientos de páginas de resultados, la mayoría relativos al nombre "Marciano". De hecho es complicado encontrar casos que se refieran al planeta Marte. He localizado [uno de 1915](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0001175090&page=242&search=marciano&lang=es) que habla sobre cómo construir un espejo reflector para que dos telegrafistas, uno terrestre y otro marciano, pudieran comunicarse (espoiler: debería tener 83 kilómetros de diámetro).

También he encontrado en la hemeroteca [un texto que dice así](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0026229710&page=188&search=martiano&lang=es):

> *La obra de reconstitución de todo lo destruído por el fuego martiano de cinco años de guerra no se inicia.*
>
> Revista nacional de economía. 1919, n.º 20, página 188.

No he llegado a entender a qué se refiere con *martiano*, pero desde luego no se refiere al planeta Marte. La cercanía de las fechas con los primeros textos que hablan de los *marcianos* me da a entender que sí que existió una colisión con la palabra "martiano" que ya existía con otro significado.

Comment: @walen bueno, no me extrañaría que fuera así: "martiano" para relativo al dios y "marciano" para relativo al planeta. Igual así la gente de ciencia se quiso distanciar de la mitología. Pero en todo caso es una buena pregunta.

Comment: Y antes que "marciano" tenemos "marcial" donde ya se ha perdido la *t*. También marzo viene de Marte.